# Show jQuery Modal Progress Bar during getJSON load of data

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, getjson

I am trying to present a modal dialog while I load my data. The flow looks like this:

```
showProgressBar();

$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
});

loadData(file);

$.ajaxSetup({
  async: true
});

removeProgressBar();
```

I have also tried this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
});

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
 showProgressBar();
});

loadData(file);

$.ajaxSetup({
  async: true
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
  removeProgressBar();
});
```

My functions look like:

```
function showProgressBar(){

    var theBody = d3.select("body")
                  .append("div")
                  .attr("title", "Processing")
                  .attr("class", "ui-widget-content uncollapsebox") 
                  .attr("id", "progressDialog")
                    .append("div")
                       .attr("id", "progressbar")
                       .attr("width",200)
                       .attr("height",20)

$(function() {
  $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    value: false
  });
 });

$(function() {
    $( "#progressDialog" ).dialog({modal: true,
                                  closeOnEscape: false
                                  }); 
});

}

function removeProgressBar(){
   $('#progressDialog').dialog('close');
   $('#progressDialog').remove(); 
}
```

My load file looks like:

```
function loadData(nameOfFile){

  $(function(){
      $.getJSON("...",function(data){ 

      }).error(function(){
          console.log('error loading data!');
      });
  });
  console.log("done with getJSON");
 }
```

I have tried many variations but either the modal isn't shown or it is shown and is not removed or it is shown and then I get an error saying : Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'. The show and remove functions work just fine when called by themselves from e.g. the console.

p.s. I use the async: false because I compute on my data right after the load and if I don't do that of course it does not wait for all the data to be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you set async to false, your browser will freeze until the ajax query returns.  If you want to have context cues like a progress bar, you need to keep async as true and call `removeProgressBar` in the success callback of your ajax call.

Comment: HI climbage, Thanks for the quick reply. Regarding this part of my post: "I compute on my data right after the load" Could you advise how I handle the flow then so I can have the progress bar and prevent the program from moving on until the data is fully loaded. Does it really mean calling everything after the load in my success callback?